# Library to write an Excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am using Microsoft Excel Interop library for exporting Excel file. However, the limit of this library is that:

- Require the user's computer must have Microsoft Excel.
- When write the content, Microsoft Excel must be opened to automate.
- To save file, user must do manually: click on File -> Save.

I need a library:

- Write the content to memory with Excel format.
- Save this content to file programmatically.

**Notes:** I use .net 2.0 and C#.

Thanks.

Comment: I've had a few projects where "Excel format" meant "file I can open in Excel", and delimited text was a simple solution.

Comment: Right. But minimum I can open it in Excel 2003. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have used [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for .xlsx reading/writing and it has worked great

Comment: +1 I've used it also. Writing excel spreadsheets > 65k rows was a breeze.

Comment: .xlsx is compatibled with Excel 2003? I need a Excel format which can be opened with Microsoft Excel 2003. Thanks.

Comment: Excel 2003 can open .xlsx files if you install the Microsoft compatibility pack : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-for-word-excel-and-powerpoint-2007-file-formats-HA010168676.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve this without having Excel installed is to just write the file format directly.  Microsoft documented the file format a few years ago.  You can find them at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118.aspx.

**Update**
I've just found EPPlus.  Check it out at http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ODBC or OLE connector to read and write an Excel file. However, I am not sure if you can create a file with it, you might need to keep a dummy-empty file with the correct layout.

Update: It is, accordingly to comment below from @Joel Gauvreau possible to create an excel file using this technique.

Links:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/microsoftexcel/article.php/c1131

Comment: It is what I'm doing, and you can create an empty file with the correct layout, dump the raw data in a worksheet. You can create some  nice looking worksheet that link to this data if you need.  It works well.  The file does not need to exist, you must however create the schema first if you are not using an existing file.

Comment: @Joel thank you, I wasn't sure if it was possible. I will add a note of your response in the answer.

Comment: The result is much nicer with an existing file that you can format before hand.  By creating the file with the OleDbConnection you just get a plain list of the data.

Comment: This answer pretty much sums it up : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c/151048#151048